# How to add a custom column to Magento's "Manage Customers" view

Tags: magento

In order for a user to become an active member of our site, they need to click on the confirmation link sent to their email address. When we click on "Manage Customers" on the backend of Magento, we can see which customer group the customer belongs in, but we cannot tell whether or not they have activated their account without clicking on each individual account. Is there a way we can add a column to show and filter users who have activated / not activated their account?

Please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the value that tells if an account is activated or not is stored in an attribute, this extension should do the trick : [Enhanced Admin Grids](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/enhanced-admin-grids-editor.html)